# Add scroll playback controls to AVPlayer like in Photos app

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, video-streaming, avplayer

I'm creating AVPlayer view to watch the stream from CCTV. And I want to make playback controls in a video like in Photos app at iPhone(open Photos, play some video, at the bottom, it will be UIScrollView with some screenshots of your video) like at image below.
May I ask you some help on how to create something like this?
And this is my first question here, so sorry if something wrong. =)

ScrollView playback

[image]

Comment: There's no one way to do it, but I'd take some snapshots from the video, let's say, every 10 seconds and put them on a scrollview. after that, I will listen to scrollViewDidScroll delegate function and change the location in the video accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

AVPlayer cannot do this for streaming. The suggestion made on snapshots would also not be close to your want of getting the same behaviour as on local preview of videos in the Photos App on iOS.

If you are looking for this kind of experience I would recommend heading over to [movi.ai](https://movi.ai) to get your hands on our cross platform solution with this ready out of the box.